# How to reduce indentation level of argument help in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using Python's `argparse`, and I want there to be less indentation of the argument help text. This is what `argparse` is generating:

```
$ ./help.py -h
usage: help.py [-h] [--program-argument PROGRAM_ARGUMENT]

Description of program

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --program-argument PROGRAM_ARGUMENT
                        This is some help text about --program-argument. For example:

                            --program-argment "You can supply a string as the program argument"
```

I want it to generate something more like this:

```
$ ./help.py -h
usage: help.py [-h] [--program-argument PROGRAM_ARGUMENT]

Description of program

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --program-argument PROGRAM_ARGUMENT
      This is some help text about --program-argument. For example:

          --program-argment "You can supply a string as the program argument"
```

Is that achievable? This is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import argparse

HELP_TEXT = """\
This is some help text about --program-argument. For example:

    --program-argment "You can supply a string as the program argument"
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    argument_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
        description=('Description of program'))
    argument_parser.add_argument(
        '--program-argument',
        help=HELP_TEXT
    )
    args, unknown = argument_parser.parse_known_args()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`argparse` formatters support several initialization values that can help control some formatting. They all derive from `HelpFormatter`, which has this `__init__` method.

```
class HelpFormatter(object):
    """Formatter for generating usage messages and argument help strings.

    Only the name of this class is considered a public API. All the methods
    provided by the class are considered an implementation detail.
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 prog,
                 indent_increment=2,
                 max_help_position=24,
                 width=None):
    # stuff
```

The `max_help_position` is used when determining how far to indent help sub-messages, so you could try reducing it to something like `10` or `12` to get less indentation of your messages.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse

HELP_TEXT = """\
This is some help text about --program-argument. For example:

    --program-argment "You can supply a string as the program argument"
"""

less_indent_formatter = lambda prog: argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter(prog, max_help_position=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    argument_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=less_indent_formatter,
        description=('Description of program'))
    argument_parser.add_argument(
        '--program-argument',
        help=HELP_TEXT
    )
    args, unknown = argument_parser.parse_known_args()
```

This results in:

```
usage: help.py [-h] [--program-argument PROGRAM_ARGUMENT]

Description of program

optional arguments:
  -h, --help
          show this help message and exit
  --program-argument PROGRAM_ARGUMENT
          This is some help text about --program-argument. For example:

              --program-argment "You can supply a string as the program argument"
```

A value of `6` looks like this:

```
usage: help.py [-h] [--program-argument PROGRAM_ARGUMENT]

Description of program

optional arguments:
  -h, --help
      show this help message and exit
  --program-argument PROGRAM_ARGUMENT
      This is some help text about --program-argument. For example:

          --program-argment "You can supply a string as the program argument"
```

Comment: Why does `less_indent_formatter` formatter have to be a `lambda`? Our linter complained about that so I changed to `def` but got errors like `length of metavar tuple does not match nargs`.

Comment: @Drew the lambda was just the most convenient, a method works as well. If you’re running into the `length of metavar` problem, make sure that the method’s argument is called `prog` because that’s how `argparse` will call it. If you need further help, let me know - I’ll respond when I get home and have access to a computer.

Comment: Ah yeah I had changed the argument name to `program`. Didn't realize it was passed via kwarg.